# Doctrine2 filled relation generates null value

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have a problem with doctrine2 relations and events.

I have relation like this:

Point:

```
My\Entity\Point:
type: entity
table: null
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: User
    game:
        targetEntity: Game
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    point:
        type: integer
    date:
        type: datetime
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Game:

```
My\Entity\Game:
type: entity
table: null
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: User
oneToMany:
    points:
        targetEntity: Point
        mappedBy: game
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    date:
        type: datetime
    win:
        type: boolean
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

so:

- one user can have many games
- one game can have many points
- one point can be related with only one game
- one user can have many points

additionally, I have some eventlistener

```
/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof Game && $args->hasChangedField('win')) {
        $this->point->setUser($entity->getUser());
        $this->point->setGame($entity);

        switch(true){
            case $args->getNewValue('win'):
                $this->point->setPoint(1);
                break;
            case $args->getOldValue('win'):
                $this->point->setPoint(-1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $this->haveToBeFlush = true;
    }
}

/**
 * @param PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs
 */
public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    if ($this->haveToBeFlush === true) {
        $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->persist($this->point);
        $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
}
```

- if user win/loose the game, i want to create point (1/-1) for him.

After postFlush, I can see record in db like this:

```
id;user_id;point;date;game_id
6;17;-1;2014-03-26 15:02:01;NULL
```

I don't know, why there appears null value for game_id

Answer (score 0):

All right, now all clear.

First moment, I though that problem can appear when i'm working with entity, for which I've created event listener "postUpdate". I was wrong.

**Problem was with the cache.** After clearing cache and restarting apache, everything is ok.